# spring boot swagger, how to write optional parameter and filter url /{storeId}?product={productId}&expand=grocery,electronics,clothing"

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger

Hi I am doing swagger in spring boot project. I am doing swagger definition for endpoint method.
Given `GET /{storeId}?product={productId}&expand=grocery,electronics,clothing`
I want to write swagger for this given url. How do I do?

First of all, after {storeId}, **? means optional, right?**
so can I do `@RequestParam(required = false)String productId?` for product={productId} part.?

Secondly, **what does & mean** in the url?
I am not sure but that's filtering?

My try was

```
  @GetMapping("/storeId"})
public ResponseEntity<Product> getProduct(
@PathVariable("storeId")String storeId,
@RequestParam(required = false) String productId, 
@RequestParam(required = false, name = "expand") Set<ProductEnum> products)
{//some code}
```

and ProductEnum is nothing but just have grocery,electronics,clothing values.

one more question,

```
@GetMapping("/{storeId"})
```

or

```
@GetMapping("/{storeId}?product={productId}&expand=grocery,electronics,clothing")
```

which one is correct?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@GetMapping("/{storeId}")` is the correct way.

For you, swagger can be something like this-

```
paths:
  /{storeId}:
    get:
      summary: Get a store by ID
      parameters:
        - in: query
          name: productId
          schema:
            type: string
          required: false
        - in: query
          name: expand
          schema:
            type: array
            items:
              type: string
          required: false
```

You can refer to this [Describing Parameters](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-parameters/).